# os.chdir(folder) doesn't work in Python 3.11

Tags: python-3.x, python-os

I've just updated to Python 3.11 from 3.9 by reinstalling Anaconda and this super-basic piece of code now doesn't work in Jupyter-lab.

```
import os

folder = r'Z:\Chris_ResearchDrive\20220520_horopito'
os.chdir(folder)
```

Throws:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 4
      1 import os
      3 folder = r'Z:\Chris_ResearchDrive\20220520_horopito'
----> 4 os.chdir(folder)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Z:\\Chris_ResearchDrive\\20220520_horopito'
```

Addition 20230926 @ 20:10
I've tried all possible permutations of single and double forward and backward slashes and with removing the 'r' at the beggining for a raw string. This still doesn't work, which tells me something as this should absolutely work.

Addition 20230926 @ 20:37
This seems to be a specific issue with the network drive location I'm trying to access. Local drives open without a problem. So, this works:

```
folder = r'E:\local_folder'
```

This doesn't:

```
folder = r'Z:\network_folder'
```

Again, this is **new** behaviour with my Anaconda reinstall and Python 3.11. I have had no problem pasting network drive paths into Python 3.9 and accessing them using os.chdir for years.

**Apologies** for the confusion over the debugging output in my original post. I tried to simplify the folder path but forgot to make the same change to the debugging output. I've now provided averything exactly as-is.

Comment: That error message doesn't match the posted code. The path is completely different.

Comment: For me python 3.11 os.chdir works - probably you have path issue. Also consider using Path from pathlib to construct your path variable.

Comment: @Drako - The code has worked for years as-is. Why should I load another library to make somethign work that should work without it?

Comment: If you're saying you really ran code with a hardcoded path that doesn't say `20220520_horopito` anywhere, and you got an error message that says `20220520_horopito`, then you're probably looking at the wrong code.

Comment: @Drako - The code has worked for years as-is. Why should I load another library to make somethign work that should work without it?

Comment: I don't believe you're showing us your actual code. It is simply implausible that each backslash in the input path would become two backslashes in the error message without any additional code on your part. What @user2357112 said proves the same as well.

Comment: @blhsing - You are correct. Apologies for the confusion. I have edited the file path in the code and forget to edit the file path in the output accordingly. I thought this would be helpful but I messed it up. I have edited the question to show the actual file path I'm trying to access. The error message, with the extra slashes, is as output. However, I had been trying lots of slash permutations so I must have pasted the wrong output in.  I have reproduced this with the original folder path used when I first encountered the issue.

Comment: Looking at the edited question, this looks like it's probably a permissions issue or a typo. See if you can run `os.listdir('Z:\\')`. If you can, then try `os.listdir('Z:\\Chris_ResearchDrive')`.

Comment: @user2357112 - No, that also throws an error:   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Z:\\'

Answer (score 0):

I think insted of this :

```py
import os

folder = r'Z:\Chris_ResearchDrive\folder'
os.chdir(folder)
```

You should try this :

```py
import os

folder = 'Z:/Chris_ResearchDrive/folder'
os.chdir(folder)
```

Comment: I've edited my question to mention that I've tried all slash permutations. Still doesn't work.